# Laravel Vite with package development

Tags: laravel, vite

How to use laravel vite with custom package development. I tried to add my path to vite.config.js but am getting an error.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({

            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
          //  input: ['../Packages/Plugin/Customers/public/css/styles'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

I tried to duplicate this in my package folder but same error. Can you please assist.

Comment: Where's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I followed Kamlesh login, I was able to create vite.config.js file inside my custom package as shown below.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/asset/css/settings.css',
            'resources/asset/js/custom.js',
            'resources/asset/js/ecstore_profile.js',
            'resources/asset/js/general_settings.js',
        ]),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'settings': '/resources/asset/css/settings.css',
            'custom': '/resources/asset/js/custom.s',
            'profile': '/resources/asset/js/ecstore_profile.js',
            'general': '/resources/asset/js/general_settings.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Then I added each file to the vite.config.js file. Then run build inside the custom package and publish this to laravel public folder. all working fine.